# Only for the top ones

Tags: word, visual

**I'm looking for an 8-letter word. What's the word?**

---

[image]

```
                      In between, from left to right: B___Y_____B____G____R__
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The concealed 8-letter word is:

> **OLYMPICS** - a sporting event 'only for the top [athletes]' (as per the title).

The circles...

> ...represent 'rings'. The logo of the Olympic games comprises an arrangement of 5 coloured rings.

The dots...

> ...are the centre-points of the rings in question. Arranging five rings accordingly (with overlap) creates the basic logo structure.

And as for B___Y_____B____G____R__

> ...these are the initial letters of the colours used in the logo from left to right: BLUE, YELLOW, BLACK, GREEN and RED.
>
>  Putting all this information together gives us the picture at the centre of this puzzle:
>
>  [image: Olympic rings logo]

Comment: I was confused as to why there are 10 rings in the picture 

Comment: @LukasRotter Ditto. I *think* it's just obfuscation, as using *the correct number* of them would probably be an absolutely instant giveaway...

Comment: Yes, that was exactly why I chose ten, would've been too obvious otherwise. Looks like it still was pretty obvious though :D Nice speed and well done!